# Considerations while using Non-English [say Chinese, Japanese] field names in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, localization

I tried to create a DE with field with Non-English [Japanese characters]

- Found NO issue creating Data Extension
- Found NO issue while exporting manually from DE records tab.
- Found NO issue while importing back the CSV

However, wanted to re-confirm with community if there is things I should be aware or take care!
Just to avoid any pitfall!

As per official doc: only [these](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_data_extensions_name_restricted_characters.htm&type=5) characters are NOT supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we ran a test with chinese a while ago with similar (so far, positive) results that I can share:

All of these refer to the usage of Chinese symbols:

Content Builder:

- Email name - OK
- External Key of an Email - OK
- Content - OK
- Dynamic Content (Dynamic Subject) - OK

DEs:

- name - OK
- external Key - OK
- fieldnames - OK
- record data - OK; a symbol has the length of 1.

Automation Studio

- Automation & Activity Name - OK
- Automation & Activity External Key - OK
- Query using chinese fields and DE-Name - OK

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jonas for the detailed verification/observation.